# Currying functions in R

Tags: r, currying

Is it possible to use [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) in `R`?

One possibility is to have special `paste` functions (it can be considered as a follow up to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322546/operation-overloading-in-r)), e.g. (in incorrect code):

```
'%+%' <- (sep)function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep=sep)
"a"%+%("")"b"%+%("_")"c" #gives "ab_c"
```

What would be a possible implementation in `R`?

PS: The `paste` is just an example, I am curious about the possibilities of `R`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228544/higher-level-functions-in-r-is-there-an-official-compose-operator-or-curry-func higher level functions in R - is there an official compose operator or curry function?

Comment: The proto package can do currying within the context of proto objects.  For example, if `p` is a proto object then `p$ls` is `ls` with `p` inserted into the first slot and `p$ls()` runs it. In fact `p$ls()` is the same as `ls(p)` except that it looks for `ls` in `p` and if not found looks into the ancestors of `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to curry in R, and there is a definition in the ROxygen package. See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228544/higher-level-functions-in-r-is-there-an-official-compose-operator-or-curry-func)

Answer (score 28):

The standard place for functional programming in R is now the `functional` library, this library substitutes the `ROxigen` library that is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228544/higher-level-functions-in-r-is-there-an-official-compose-operator-or-curry-fun) :

```
library(functional)
newfunc <- Curry(oldfunc,x=5)
```

Comment: The Curry function mentioned here is not currying. It's doing partial application. Followed this answer to the functional library, so I thought it was worth putting up a warning ;).