# How to pass some (but not all) further arguments with "..."

Tags: r

One of my in-progress functions calls `grep()` with `value = TRUE` hard-coded. I'd like to pass all of the further arguments **except** `value` to `grep()` through with `...`.  The two functions below are tests I've done so far, neither of which gets the job done.

**What is the best way to exclude one or more further arguments when using** `...` **?**

Practice function 1:

```
f <- function(pattern, x, ...)
{
    dots <- list(...)
    if('value' %in% names(dots)) 
        dots <- dots[!grepl('value', names(dots))]
    grep(pattern, x, value = TRUE, ...)
}

XX <- c('bct', 'abc', 'fds', 'ddabcff', 'jkl')    
## test f()
f('abc', XX, value = TRUE) ## to test the error if user enters 'value' argument
# Error in grep(pattern, x, value = TRUE, ...) : 
#     formal argument "value" matched by multiple actual arguments
f('abc', XX, invert = TRUE)
# [1] "bct" "fds" "jkl"
f('ABC', XX, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] "abc"     "ddabcff"
```

Practice function 2:

```
h <- function(pattern, x, ...) x[grep(pattern, x, ...)]    
## test h()
h('abc', XX, value = TRUE)
# [1] NA NA
h('abc', XX, invert = TRUE)
# [1] "bct" "fds" "jkl"
h('ABC', XX, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] "abc"     "ddabcff"
```

Comment: Is there a problem with including value as a named parameter?

Comment: Yes, it must be set to TRUE.  I'll post the snippet from the function I'm writing.

Comment: A workaround could be to change the last line in your `f` to `do.call("grep", c(list(pattern = pattern), list(x = x), value = TRUE, dots))` where in "dots" you have excluded "value" argument.

Comment: @alexis_laz, that seems to work nicely.

Comment: @alexis_laz, would you mind posting an answer?  I'm having a bit of trouble implementing it given the snippet I provided.

Comment: You can check out the `functional` library. If you use `Curry` thou it will have a similar problem to `f`. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228544/higher-level-functions-in-r-is-there-an-official-compose-operator-or-curry-fun and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354364/currying-functions-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just make value a named parameter but ignore the input - that way it will never be a part of the dots to begin with.

```
f <- function(pattern, x, value = "hahaThisGetsIgnored", ...){
   grep(pattern, x, value = TRUE, ...)
}
```

You can also use the idea in the answer @MatthewLundberg gave but by doing the argument manipulation without Curry so you don't need the functional package

```
f <- function(pattern, x, ...){
  dots <- list(...)
  # Remove value from the dots list if it is there
  dots$value <- NULL
  args <- c(list(pattern = pattern, x = x, value = TRUE), dots)
  do.call(grep, args)
}
```

Comment: Or even just `dots$value <- NULL` will work to get rid of it whether it's there or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `Curry` with `do.call`:

```
require(functional)
f <- function(pattern, x, ...)
{
  dots <- list(...)
  dots <- dots[!grepl('value', names(dots))]
  do.call(Curry(grep, pattern=pattern, x=x, value=TRUE), dots)
}
```

`Curry` provides the known arguments, and `dots` supplies everything other than "value" in `...`.