# How can I avoid undesired argument matching?

Tags: r, argument-passing, named-parameters

Suppose I write such a function in R:

```
fun1 <- function(x,...,simplify=TRUE,sort=TRUE) {
   # do something here ...
}
```

In the function, `...` is supposed to be a number of expressions that are evaluated in specific environments. However, sometimes it is possible that the expression itself is `simplify=FALSE` or `sort=FALSE` which are intended for `...` not the arguments of `fun1`.

I learned from some packages that the author avoid using potential conflicts between possible named values for `...` and existing argument names. Therefore they write the function in the following manner:

```
fun1 <- function(.data, ..., .simplify = TRUE, .sort = TRUE) {
  # do something here ...
}
```

It does not solve the problem but avoids many potential conflicts under the assumption that typical data input will not frequently use `.data`, `.simplify`, and `.sort` in the expression.

What is the best practice to solve or walk around this problem?

Comment: maybe something like the MoreArgs argument in `mapply`? take a look at the source and see if that is helpful

Comment: Are you trying to "hard-code" certain `...` arguments? If so, the answers and comments in  [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856089/how-to-pass-some-but-not-all-further-arguments-with) might be useful.  You might also try placing the `...` after the existing arguments.

Comment: If you have arguments that match multiple functions in your "fun1", another way could be -instead of `...`- to use arguments whose input is a list of named arguments and call each function in your "fun1" using `do.call`. E.g. `fun1 = function(f2_args, f3_args) do.call(f2, f2_args); do.call(f3, c(f3_args, extra_f3_arg))`.