# How to pass arguments to a function inside *apply family functions

Tags: r, function, apply, lapply

I have the following dataset:

```
dput(tt2)
structure(c(1371.25, NA, 1373.95, NA, NA, 1373, NA, 1373.95, 
1373.9, NA, NA, 1374, 1374.15, NA, 1374, 1373.85, 1372.55, 1374.05, 
1374.15, 1374.75, NA, NA, 1375.9, 1374.05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1375, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1376.35, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1376.25, NA, 1378, 1376.5, NA, NA, NA, 1378, 
1378, NA, NA, 1378.8, 231.9, 231.85, NA, 231.9, 231.85, 231.9, 
231.8, 231.9, 232.6, 231.95, 232.35, 232, 232.1, 232.05, 232.05, 
232.05, 231.5, 231.3, NA, NA, 231.1, 231.1, 231.1, 231, 231, 
230.95, 230.6, 230.6, 230.7, 230.6, 231, NA, 231, 231, 231.45, 
231.65, 231.4, 231.7, 231.3, 231.25, 231.25, 231.4, 231.4, 231.85, 
231.75, 231.5, 231.55, 231.35, NA, 231.5, 231.5, NA, 231.5, 231.25, 
231.15, 231, 231, 231, 231.05, NA), .Dim = c(60L, 2L), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "Asia/Calcutta", tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", index = structure(c(1459482300, 
1459483766.38983, 1459485231.77966, 1459486697.16949, 1459488162.55932, 
1459489627.94915, 1459491093.33898, 1459492558.72881, 1459494025.11864, 
1459495490.50847, 1459496955.89831, 1459498421.28814, 1459499887.67797, 
1459501353.0678, 1459502818.45763, 1459504283.84746, 1459505749.23729, 
1459507214.62712, 1459508680.01695, 1459510145.40678, 1459511610.79661, 
1459513076.18644, 1459514541.57627, 1459516007.9661, 1459517474.35593, 
1459518939.74576, 1459520405.13559, 1459521870.52542, 1459523335.91525, 
1459524804.30508, 1459526269.69492, 1459527735.08475, 1459529200.47458, 
1459530667.86441, 1459532134.25424, 1459533600.64407, 1459535066.0339, 
1459536531.42373, 1459537996.81356, 1459539702.20339, 1459541167.59322, 
1459542634.98305, 1459544100.37288, 1459545565.76271, 1459547031.15254, 
1459548496.54237, 1459549961.9322, 1459551429.32203, 1459552894.71186, 
1459554360.10169, 1459555829.49153, 1459557294.88136, 1459558760.27119, 
1459560225.66102, 1459561691.05085, 1459563160.44068, 1459564625.83051, 
1459566091.22034, 1459567557.61017, 1459569028), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta"), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", 
"B")), class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

I want to learn how to pass arguments to a function inside the apply family functions.
1st example:
Since there are NAs in the data, mean function returns NA. So I want to pass `na.rm=TRUE`:

```
tt<-apply.daily(tt2, function(x) sapply(x,mean(na.rm=TRUE)))
```

But it returns:

```
Error in mean.default(na.rm = TRUE) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

2nd example:
I want to use period.sum function that takes only single column values and requires index of the column.

```
tt<-lapply(tt2, period.sum, endpoints(tt2))

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)
```

I know the 2nd example can me solved with `period.apply` but as lapply is a general type function can the 2nd example be solved using lapply also?

Comment: `sapply(x, mean, na.rm=TRUE)` I presume. Or possibly even just: `apply.daily(tt2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: You could try to curry your existing function to create a new function that you apply.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228544/higher-level-functions-in-r-is-there-an-official-compose-operator-or-curry-fun

Comment: @cricket_007 nice reference but sadly I am still stuck at beginner level.

Comment: @Procrastinatus Maximus  I have gone through the referred question. And my 2nd example show that I  applied it exactly. But I still get the error and hence my question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments in all the functions of the `apply` family through the ellipsis (`...`) argument, cf. the [help page on sapply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html). Now, `apply.daily` is just an extension to `xts` objects, see `?apply.daily`.

```
 apply.daily(tt2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
#apply.daily(  x,  FUN,        ...)
```

Comment: See my 2nd example

Comment: @runjumpfly the answer also applies to your 2nd example.

Comment: @HongOoi Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)

Comment: @runjumpfly [you should not ask more than one question per post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post). But you could do `period.apply(tt2,endpoints(tt2),colSums,na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: What I wanted to ask using 2nd example was how to pass argument to endpoints in the period.sum in the lapply.

Comment: If asking sub questions is not acceptable then I will ask it as a separate question. But What I asked is essentially how to pass different arguments to  apply functions.

Comment: @runjumpfly For that there already exist answered questions: [passing several arguments to FUN of lapply (and others *apply)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427253/passing-several-arguments-to-fun-of-lapply-and-others-apply). For you,
`lapply(tt2,colSums,na.rm=TRUE)` is equivalent to the above but the return type is a list (as that is what `lapply` returns).

Comment: I have gone through the referred question. And my 2nd example show that I  applied it exactly. But I still get the error and hence my question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Yes and I will accept your answer also, But I was thinking is it possible to use period.sum within lapply function.  I am confused becasue ellipsis (...) is not taking endpoints(tt2). This is my last query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126077/discussion-between-therkel-and-runjumpfly).